# List of countries an Indian can visit without applying for visa

Tags: online-resources, indian-citizens, international-travel, visa-free-entry

Are there any countries an Indian citizen can visit without a visa?

Comment: Yes. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Indian_citizens

Comment: Have you heard of Google?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Indian_citizens), India's passport ranks 76th in the world at present for visa-free access (or visa on arrival access), and gives you access to 52 countries and territories.

Most of these are in SE Asia, some in Africa and Bolivia.  For more information, rather than listing them all out as they may change, see:

[Visa requirements for Indian citizens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Indian_citizens).

Answer (score 3):

VisaHQ.com has a list which gives you a good idea about the places a citizen of any country can travel with or without the need for a visa. Give that a try.

Here is the exact link from where you can get the details:
https://www.visahq.com/citizens/India/

The list below is allowed for tourism:

- Bhutan
- British Virgin Islands
- Dominica
- Ecuador
- El Salvador
- Fiji
- Grenada
- Haiti
- Honduras
- Hong Kong
- Jamaica
- Kosovo
- Macau
- Montserrat
- Micronesia
- Mauritius
- Nepal
- Niue
- Nicaragua
- Palau
- Pitcairn Island
- Saint Helena
- Saint Kitts Nevis
- Seychelles
- Saint Vincent Grenadines
- Samoa
- Trinidad Tobago
- Tuvalu
- Vanuatu

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @MarkMayo Added the list :)